# How can I take action when user clicks on checkbox in any infoWindow?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-maps

I can get it to work in regular webpage following examples found in this forum.

But trying to take action when user checks or unchecks (clicks or changes) a checkbox on any of 25 infoWindows ... cannot figure out any selector to make it work ...

full test page: http://mosttraveledpeople.com/beach/maps2.php

```
//
// latest test code (based on research in  this forum)

     $(document).ready(function(){
        $('input[type=checkbox]').click(function(){
          if($(this).is(':checked')){
           // alert($(this).attr('id'));  
              alert ("checked");
         }   
        else {alert("unchecked");}
         });
       });



//

         var markers = [];

        myLatlng=new google.maps.LatLng("-4.293099","55.699843");
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker(
            {icon:'http://mosttraveledpeople.com/beach/beachicon_red32.png',
         position: myLatlng,
         map: map,
           title: 'Anse Lazio, Praslin Island, Seychelles',
         events:
             {
            mouseout: function(){ infoWindo.close(); }
           } 
        } 
      );

             var infoWindowContent = "<table border='0' style='background-color: white'><tr><td><img src='http://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-s/05/76/76/ab/anse-lazio.jpg' height='80'></td><td>Anse Lazio, Praslin Island, Seychelles<br><form id='upbeach6' name='upbeach6' action='#' method='post' onSubmit='return false;'><input type='hidden' name='beachid' value='6'>Visited: <input type='checkbox' name='flag6' id='flag6' value='Y'></input></form></td></tr></table?>";
             addInfoWindow(marker, infoWindowContent);
             markers.push(marker);
```

Comment: have you try with another version of jquery? eg. 1.11.2

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in your question itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the first chunk of code you have needs to be called after the map loads, but you have it being called before the selector will select anything (because it's not rendered yet)

You have a mouseout event now -- why not add an event for the mouseover and on that event you can use the jquery selector for checkboxes within that infobox.

Or after you create the marker, you could do something like:

```
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() {
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type=checkbox]').click(function(){
      if($(this).is(':checked')){
       // alert($(this).attr('id'));  
          alert ("checked");
     }   
    else {alert("unchecked");}
     });
   });
  });
```

Good luck
-Mike

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much. I got it to work using your code.
Now I need to change it to actually do the ajax update call I need (instead of just alert :-) , but that is for another post if I get stuck...
you rock! (and I will slowly keep learning)

Answer (score 0):

The checkbox is only attached to the DOM after the infowindow is opened.  You have two options:

1. use an onclick function defined in the HTML in the infowindow:

   ```
   var infoWindowContent = "<table border='0' style='background-color: white'><tr><td><img src='http://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-s/05/76/76/ab/anse-lazio.jpg' height='80'></td><td>Anse Lazio, Praslin Island, Seychelles<br><form id='upbeach6' name='upbeach6' action='#' method='post' onSubmit='return false;'><input type='hidden' name='beachid' value='6'>Visited: <input type='checkbox' name='flag6' id='flag6' value='Y' onclick='alert(\'foo\');'></input></form></td></tr></table?>";
   ```

2. Use JQuery to add the listener after the infowindow is attached to the DOM, in an `domready` event listener on the infowindow.